# Profiling `npm ci` to understand slowness

Tags: npm

`npm ci` has become really slow (~3 minutes) in the last month, and I tend to blame specific dependencies that were added in the month, or dependency updates the occur during that time.

Is there a way to profile `npm ci` to find bottlenecks?